# Using docker-compose to build development and deployment pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

I am trying to create a Docker Compose file to build my local development and deployment pipeline for ReactJS project.

**Some Context**: Locally I start the server on `3000` port. For deployment, I export the static artefacts, deploy it on S3 and invalidate my CloudFront files.

I have built a [Docker Image](https://github.com/a6kme/node-aws-cli-docker) which contains node and AWS CLI, and I am using that as my base `FROM` Image.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM a6kme/node-aws-cli:v1

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  esnextwebjourney_node_modules:
services:
  esnextwebjourney:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - esnextwebjourney_node_modules:/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: >
      sh -c "npm run build && npm run start"
```

Which works, but every time I have to go on and update the command to either start the server `npm run build && npm run start` or deploy it on s3 and CloudFront i.e `npm run build && npm run export && npm run deploy`.

**My Question Is -**
Can I create a docker-compose.yml file like below, and I can then may be call `docker-compose run start --build` or `docker-compose run deploy --build` and which will serve both my purpose.

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  esnextwebjourney_node_modules:
services:
  build:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - esnextwebjourney_node_modules:/app/node_modules
    command: npm run build
  start:
    depends_on:
      - build
    command: npm run start
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  export:
    depends_on:
      - build
    command: npm run export
  deploy:
    depends_on:
      - export
    command: npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an override:

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  esnextwebjourney:
    command: "npm run build && npm run export && npm run deploy"
```

When you want to export you can run: docker-compose up -d --build
When you only want to deploy: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build

The second version ignores the override.

Another solution would be to use an environment variable for the command. This way your docker-compose.yml stays always the same and you only have to export a new environment variable before running it. You can automate that with a shell script.

What you want to build also might work if you create a named volume and you share it between ALL the services. But I like more my solution :)

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I am just trying to avoid creating separate compose file for this use case. Creating a shell file using environment variable also sounds kind of a hack. Is there no support for named commands in docker-compose which I can provide as command line argument when invoking docker-compose up?

Comment: I am really sorry that you see creating a shell script a hack... You could overwrite the entrypoint for your service: docker-compose run <some service> --entrypoint "npm run build && npm run start". But that means changing a bit the logic of the docker-compose file

Comment: I will give the --entrypoint method a try. But from the lack of answer that I was expecting, I suppose it can not be done the way I was thinking it could be done. Still, I would wait for some different perspective from other authors. Thanks!